# Google Foobar: How to find edge cases and identify test cases. Python

Tags: python

Problem

> **Fuel Injection Perfection**
>
> Commander Lambda has asked for your help to refine the automatic
>   quantum antimatter fuel injection system for her LAMBCHOP doomsday
>   device. It's a great chance for you to get a closer look at the
>   LAMBCHOP - and maybe sneak in a bit of sabotage while you're at it -
>   so you took the job gladly.
>
> Quantum antimatter fuel comes in small pellets, which is convenient
>   since the many moving parts of the LAMBCHOP each need to be fed fuel
>   one pellet at a time. However, minions dump pellets in bulk into the
>   fuel intake. You need to figure out the most efficient way to sort and
>   shift the pellets down to a single pellet at a time.
>
> The fuel control mechanisms have three operations:
>
> Add one fuel pellet Remove one fuel pellet Divide the entire group of
>   fuel pellets by 2 (due to the destructive energy released when a
>   quantum antimatter pellet is cut in half, the safety controls will
>   only allow this to happen if there is an even number of pellets) Write
>   a function called answer(n) which takes a positive integer as a string
>   and returns the minimum number of operations needed to transform the
>   number of pellets to 1. The fuel intake control panel can only display
>   a number up to 309 digits long, so there won't ever be more pellets
>   than you can express in that many digits.
>
> For example: answer(4) returns 2: 4 -> 2 -> 1 answer(15) returns 5: 15
>   -> 16 -> 8 -> 4 -> 2 -> 1
>
> **Test cases**
>
> Inputs: (string) n = "4" Output: (int) 2
>
> Inputs: (string) n = "15" Output: (int) 5

Here is my solution:

```
import math
import decimal
def answer(n):
    n = long(n)
    if n <= 1 or n >= long('9' * 309):
        return 0
    # 1. Find closest power of 2
    round_threshold_adjust = math.log(3,2)- (1.5)
    log_n = math.log(n, 2)
    power = log_n - round_threshold_adjust

    # Round power down if X.50000. If n is equally between two powers of 2,
    # choose the lower power of 2. E.g. For 6, choose, 4 not 8
    power2 = long(decimal.Decimal(power).quantize(0, decimal.ROUND_HALF_DOWN))

    # 2. Calculate the difference, add to iterations
    # 3. Take log 2 of that, add that to iteration
    iters = abs(n - 2**power) + power
    return(iters)
```

My solution currently passes 3 out of the 10 test cases. I believe the other test cases are edge cases. May you please give me some pointers on how I can identify where my code is failing? (I do not have access to the test cases)

Here are some of the test cases I have tried:

```
assert answer(15) == 5
assert answer(4) == 2
assert answer(3) == 2
assert answer(2) == 1
assert answer(6) == 4
assert answer(7) == 4
assert answer(10) == 5
assert answer(1024) == 10
assert answer(1025) == 11
assert answer(1026) == 12
assert answer(1027) == 13
assert answer(768) == 256 + 9
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understood correctly, given 768 pellets you need 256+9 steps to transform that to 1 pellet?

I can do it in 10 steps:

- Divide 768 by 2
- Repeat 7 more times -> you end up with 3 pellets
- Subtract 1
- Subtract 1

I think your first step, adding/subtracting until you land at a power of 2, is not the fastest solution.

I'm not sure how to code a better solution, but maybe this points you in the right direction. Intuitively, my next step would be to look at the binary representation of a number, and translate the allowed operations to that representation. This might simplify the creation of the correct algorithm.

Comment: For example, look at the binary representation of 768. It's got a lot of zeros at the right end that you can successively kill by dividing by 2 right away.

Comment: I'm exploring your tip on looking at the binary representation of the number.. 768's binary representation is '1 100 000 000'. It's a really interesting approach that I haven't thought of. I haven't studied number theory before, but I have a hunch that the solution takes into account # of consecutive 0's.. hmm

Comment: I've got a solution that uses bit manipulation and returns the result for 38000 concatenated 7s and 9s (whatever that number is!) in 0.6 seconds (it does the maximum possible number from the parameters of the challenge in 0.0007 seconds) and I'm still failing two of the tests. I just wonder if I'm missing something like basic error handling for negative/too large numbers or maybe my program is too verbose - I've got four helper functions - but I've tested someone's supposedly passing solution code against mine and mine is substantially faster, so it just can't be speed I'm failing on!

Answer (score 4):

Here's my solution:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
#fuel-injection-perfection
#Program to count the naximum number of operations needed to recursively divide a number by 2. Add or subtract 1 where needed.
#V2 - Initial version was done using recursion but failed for large numbers due to python limitation & performance issues.  
cnt=0
def divide(x):
    global cnt
    while(x>1):
        if (x & 1==0):
            #Dividing even number by two by shifting binary digits one step to the right.
            x=x>>1
        else:
            a=x+1
            b=x-1
            #counters ac & bc will be used to count trailing 0s
            ac=bc=0
            #count trailing 0's for x+1
            while(a & 1==0):
                a=a>>1
                ac+=1
            #count trailing 0's for x-1
            while(b & 1==0):
                b=b>>1
                bc+=1
            #go with x+1 if it has more trailing 0s in binary format. Exception is number 3 as b10 can be divided in less steps than b100.
            #edge case 3 identified by manually testing numbers 1-10.
            if (ac>bc and x!=3):
                x+=1
            else:
                x-=1
        cnt+=1

def solution(n):
    global cnt
    n=int(n)
    divide(n)
    return cnt
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the Python3 answer. I created tow function, one with adding 1 and another with subtracting 1 and then comparing which gives best answer with least steps.

```
#function for the adding 1 to the odd number
def np(n):
    c = 0
    while n > 1:
        if n%2 == 0:
            n = n/2
            c += 1
        else:
            n += 1
            c += 1
    return c

#function for the subtracting 1 to the odd number
def nn(n):
    c = 0
    while n > 1:
        if n%2 == 0:
            n = n/2
            c += 1
        else:
            n -= 1
            c += 1
    return c

#Solution function
def solution(n):
    n = int(n)
    if np(n) > nn(n):
        return nn(n)
    else:
        return np(n)
```

Hope this works, cheers.